# `Maybe` handling in Matrix manipulation in Elm

Tags: beginner, matrix, elm

I'd like to learn if my rewrite is worse than the original, less clear or less "idiomatic".

I've found [this code](https://github.com/chendrix/elm-matrix/blob/master/src/Matrix.elm#L180) that handles updating two dimensional matrixes in Elm:

```
type alias Matrix a = Array.Array (Array.Array a)
type alias Location = (Int, Int)

get : Location -> Matrix a -> Maybe a
get location m =
  Array.get (row location) m `andThen` Array.get (col location)


set : Location -> a -> Matrix a -> Matrix a
set location value m =
  update location (always value) m

update : Location -> (a -> a) -> Matrix a -> Matrix a
update location f m =
  get location m
  |> Maybe.map (
    \current ->

      Array.get (row location) m
      |> Maybe.map (
          \oldRow ->
            Array.set (col location) (f current) oldRow
            |> (\newRow -> Array.set (row location) newRow m)
      )
      |> Maybe.withDefault m
  )
  |> Maybe.withDefault m
```

I couldn't understand `update` at first so I tried to write my own (using my own domain types):

```
type Player = PlayerOne | PlayerTwo
type Slot = Empty | PlayedBy Player
type alias Board = Array.Array (Array.Array (Slot))
type alias Position = (Int, Int)

get : Board -> Position -> Maybe Slot
get board (row, column) =
    Array.get row board `Maybe.andThen` Array.get column

setPosition : Board -> Position -> Player -> Board
setPosition board (row, column) player = 
    case get board (row, column) of
        Nothing ->
            board
        Just Empty ->
            case Array.get row board of
                Nothing ->
                    board
                Just oldRow ->
                    let
                        newRow = Array.set column (PlayedBy player) oldRow
                    in
                        Array.set row newRow board
        Just s ->
            board
```

After rewriting I could understand what's going on in the original `update` function, but ended up feeling my version's clearer. This is my first day writing Elm so I'm no authority in Elm code clarity.

Comment: Your code looks very clear to me. In a way, first-day programmers are the *best* authority in clarity :) Maybe you could write an `applyAt : Int -> (a -> a) -> Array a -> Array a` function, and see if your code is clearer if you use that twice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like your code a lot more than the original! It is definitely cleaner and more obvious than the first example you gave. However, there still seems to be a process you’re repeating — get value from array, pattern match on it, update array — that you can still factor out. (The original code is guilty of this, too.)

I tried to rewrite your function in a matter that avoids this, and my code’s at the bottom; see if you find it more readable. But first, some stylistic advice on writing Elm:

- Generally, instead of writing things like `Array.Array`, it's useful to expose the type name from the data structure package you're using. Also, type parameters don’t need parentheses around them (except for grouping).

  So you can rewrite:

  ```
  type alias Board = Array.Array (Array.Array (Slot))
  ```

  to

  ```
  import Array exposing (Array)

  type alias Board = Array (Array Slot)
  ```

  which I think is a bit more Elm-y.
- A useful [design guideline](http://package.elm-lang.org/help/design-guidelines#the-data-structure-is-always-the-last-argument) (for packages, but  it’s a good idea for code in general): **the data structure is always the last argument**. You’ve reordered them from your first example, but the original order was there for a good reason: if your types look like

  ```
  f : (extra params) -> Container -> Container
  ```

  you can partially apply your function and end up with:

  ```
  f "extra" "arguments" : Container -> Container
  ```

  which is very useful for function composition and piping: often you want to take a `Container` and pipe it through a bunch of `Container -> Container` functions, like so:

  ```
  result =
      initialContainerValue
      |> f "hello" "world"
      |> someOtherStep
      |> f "oak" "fir"
  ```
- The [Elm style guide](http://elm-lang.org/docs/style-guide) contains some more recommendations that could apply to your code, but they’re more subjective. The two big ones I could think of have to do with whitespace.

  - Always have 2 empty lines between top-level declarations.
  - The examples in the guide have single empty lines between `case` branches, too.

## My version

```
{-| Apply a function at the given index in the array.

     applyAt 2 negate (fromList [50, 60, 70]) == fromList [50, 60, -70]
-}
applyAt : Int -> (a -> a) -> Array a -> Array a
applyAt i f array =
    case Array.get i array of
        Nothing ->
            array

        Just a ->
            Array.set i (f a) array


{-| Update a slot: the given player occupies it, but only if it's empty. -}
setSlot : Player -> Slot -> Slot
setSlot player slot =
    case slot of
        Empty ->
            PlayedBy player

        s ->
            s


{-| Update a slot somewhere in a board. -}
setPosition : Position -> Player -> Board -> Board
setPosition (row, column) player =
    applyAt row
        (applyAt column
            (setSlot player))
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the design guideline and explaining the argument order, I'm used to Elixir piping and thought the data structure should be first =]

Comment: `setPosition` is waaay clearer now, I see your point!